# How to change worksheet style via macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that will change the default style of a worksheet back to "Normal", but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do so. I've tried a variety of different methods to accomplish this, and have also looked at the Microsoft documentation, but I can't see a specific way to change this setting programmatically. Can someone please assist? Thank you!

This is the format I'm working with:

```
' Set style for Worksheet
Sub SetSheetStyle(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        Selection.Style = "Normal"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Style` is a `Range` property, so try something like:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Cells.Style = "Normal"
```

Comment: Okay, I've tried updating the code to that, but it still doesn't seem to be working. If I have `Sub EWMBranding_SetSheetStyle(ws As Worksheet)`, do I still need to declare `Dim ws As Worksheet:`?

Comment: Are you trying to call this as a function from some other sub?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it with this syntax:

```
' Set style for Worksheet
Sub EWMBranding_SetSheetStyle(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws
        .Cells.Style = "Bad"
    End With
End Sub
```